# react-native Signature in android

Tags: react-native, expo

I am new in react-native, I have a requirement, capture Signature,
I tried to create a running example with following - 
* expo-pixi
* react-native-signature-capture
* react-native-signature-pad (showing but can't save it)

can someone please give me a running example or successful steps? I have no specific bound with expo or CRNA. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where are you trying to save it to? The device or an external server?

Comment: external server, like a file server or db server. Basically I just need image file or base64 string.

Comment: You can use a library like this to save your image/base64 string to S3. 
https://github.com/benjreinhart/react-native-aws3
If you are using base64, you may need to do some extra configuration https://medium.com/@MirMayne/upload-a-base64-image-data-from-nodejs-to-aws-s3-bucket-6c1bd945420f

Comment: Before saving I need to get signature from user, can you give me a running example, if possible with create-react-native-app command created app.